# When I press the back button, the page does not change though url is coming correct

Tags: reactjs, pagination

I tried implementing pagination for the data in react. If I click any page , the desired page opens with the data. For example, if I press page 3 , data on page 3 gets loaded. After that when I press 5 , data on page 5 is loaded. Now if I press back button, the URL displays page 3 , but the component mounted is of page 5. Could someone help me in this?

Here is my component did mount:

componentDidMount = async () => {

```
const { state } = this.props.location;
if (state && state.mesg) {
  this.setState({
    mesg: this.props.location.state.mesg,
    mesgType: this.props.location.state.mesgType
  });
  const stateCopy = { ...state };
  delete stateCopy.mesg;
  this.props.history.replace({ state: stateCopy });
}
this.closeMesg(10000);
let pageNo = this.props.location.search.split("=");
await this.fetchCompaniesAPI(pageNo[1] || 1);
this.setState({ isLoading: false });


};
```

Here I am extracting the page number from the url and calling the API of that page.

Could someone please help me.

Do tell if you need more details.

I tried  window.onpopstate and then refresh but it did not help

I tried it with componentDidUpdate but still it is not working

```
componentDidUpdate= async (prevProps, prevState)=> {
    await this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    let pageNo = this.props.location.search.split("=");
    if (prevState.pageNo !== pageNo[1]) {
    await this.fetchCompaniesAPI(pageNo[1] || 1);
    this.setState({ isLoading: false });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you get the data from the back end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on the same route, the url will change but the component will not be remounted, hence your componentDidMount code is not executed.

You have to use componentDidUpdate for this.

Check whether your page number has changed and do a fetch again.

```
componentDidUpdate = async(prevProps: Props, prevState: State) => {
    if (prevProps.location !== this.props.location) {
      const pageNo = this.props.location.search.split("=");
      await this.fetchCompaniesAPI(pageNo[1] || 1);
    }
  }
```

Since your props will change and not your state when you press back.

Comment: how to get prevProps??

Comment: prevProps are passed by the lifecycle method itself, whenever there is a change in component, componentDidUpdate is called with prevProps and prevState as parameters.

Comment: this.props.match.params.page is giving undefined

Comment: this params is empty, I think I am not passing parameters to react router. Can you help me passing params?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replicate the same logic in the component update, also you need to only execute the logic when what changed was the pageNo.

For example:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.pageNo !== this.state.pageNo) {
    console.log('page number has changed, do logic here...')
  }
}
```

Comment: componentDidUpdate= async (prevProps, prevState)=> {
    if (prevState.pageNo !== this.state.pageNo) {
      let pageNo = this.props.location.search.split("=");
    await this.fetchCompaniesAPI(pageNo[1] || 1);
    this.setState({ isLoading: false });
    }
  }